# Excel formulas - count based on two criteria

Tags: excel, formulas

I've been struggling to get this formula to work. I have a spreadsheet where I need to find out how many of one column (BH2:BH915) contain a value (X) if another column (N2:N915) contains either 1 or 0. I've tried a bunch of versions to get it to work - this is the latest:

```
=sum(countifs(N2:N915="1","0") and (BH2:BH915="X"))
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a single formula, or using two separate ones?  Is the formula you posted one or two formulas?

Comment: are you only counting the `x` to those corresponding rows?

Comment: `=countifs(N2:N915, 0, BH2:BH915, "X") + countifs(N2:N915, 1, BH2:BH915, "X")`

Comment: =SUM(COUNTIFS(N2:N5,{0,1})) + COUNTIFS(BH2:BH5,"X"). See https://exceljet.net/formula/countifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic

Comment: I'm trying to do it in one formula - the sum of the rows in column BH that are checked only if the corresponding cell in column N equals 1 or 0

Comment: Thanks Tim Williams - that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add together the count of records with 0 and X and the count of records with 1 and X

```
=COUNTIFS(N2:N915, 0, BH2:BH915, "X") + COUNTIFS(N2:N915, 1, BH2:BH915, "X")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(BH2:BH915,"x",N2:N915,{0,1}))
```

or if you knew that the numbers in N2:N915 were integers

```
=COUNTIFS(BH2:BH915,"x",N2:N915,">="&0,N2:N915,"<="&1)
```